# jQuery function issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

My simple jQ function looks like that

```
$.fn.animateHighlight = function(highlightColor,type, duration) {
    var highlightBg = highlightColor || "#FFFF9C";
    var animateMs = 1500;
    this.stop().css(type, highlightBg).delay(duration).animate({
        type: "black"
    }, animateMs);
};
```

Calling like that

```
$("#qparamstitle").animateHighlight("red","color", 3000);
$("#params").animateHighlight("red","border-color", 3000);
```

trying to make type - variable. All works well except animation. What I did wrong, and how to get it work?

Comment: So explain what's broken and what you expect to happen instead.  Also, posting a jsFiddle example would help people be able to help you.

Comment: Hover over the down-vote arrow to see some valid reasons for down-voting.  Complaining about down-votes and calling the users of this forum names will likely get you a lot more down-votes.

Comment: @Sparky672 `type: "black"` type is variable. It may be  border-color, color .. something else. Animate function doesn't accept variable paramaeter

Comment: You cannot animate color with jQuery `.animate()`.   See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) -  _"All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value"_

Comment: Am I missing something? why these downvotes? Seems like quite good question...

Comment: @trl13, No research effort, lack of problem description, using all caps & complaining about down-votes, calling users "trolls", etc... are my guesses.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
   type: "black"
}
```

This is making an object with a key of `"type"`.  You can't use variables as keys in object literals.

You need to declare the variable first, and the set the value using `[]`.

```
$.fn.animateHighlight = function(highlightColor,type, duration) {
    var highlightBg = highlightColor || "#FFFF9C";
    var animateMs = 1500;
    var animateVal = {}; // declare object
    animateVal[type] = 'black'; // set `type` value
    this.stop().css(type, highlightBg).delay(duration).animate(animateVal, animateMs);
};
```

Comment: Oh.. seems border-color will not work. for css it is `border-color` for animate `borderColor`. How can I fix that problem?

Comment: Try to understand this solution. `border-color` will work as well as `borderColor` but _You can't use variables as keys in object literals_

Comment: @epic_syntax: `border-color` works fine in `.animate` (if you have jQuery UI included).  http://jsfiddle.net/eZDve/

Answer (score 0):

You need **jQuery UI** to be able to **[animate colors](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/)**, jQuery only does not support it.

Besides, the way you pass the option object to the animate function is not going to work. You have to create an object outside the function and pass the object:

```
$.fn.animateHighlight = function(highlightColor,type, duration) {
    var highlightBg = highlightColor || "#FFFF9C";
    var animateMs = 1500;
    // create objects for the animation options
    var o = {};
    // using the array notation
    // you can create a property of name "type"
    o[type] = 'Black';
    this.stop().css(type, highlightBg).delay(duration).animate(o, animateMs);
};
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/VPzgf/)**

Comment: I already included jquery-ui to the project. So you can suggest your jq-ui solution too.